# "Would" for Habitual Actions

Tags: modal-verbs, past-habitual

I would like to ask if the first "would" in this sentence is correct:

> "Every time she would come to our house, she would talk to Mom about that subject."

Comment: No: the first "would" is wrong. The sentence should read _Every time she came to our house, she would talk to Mom about that subject_.

Comment: @BillJ What about all those cases on   this [page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22every%20time%20she%20would%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)? Are they to be considered as errors? Is there any logical principle in support of this rule (concerning the use of the adverbial "every time", for instance) or is it a matter of mere usage?

Comment: I don't like the repetition of *would*. But okay to use the earlier one: Every time she would come to our house, she **talked** to Mom about that subject."

Comment: I find it much better style to say "Every time X happened, she would do Y" rather than "Every time X would happen...", but I don't consider the OP's sentence actually 'wrong'. Note that some of the Google results actually say "Every time, she would..."

Comment: That first "would" is typical of what *German* speakers say when they're speaking English. Strictly speaking I wouldn't say it's ungrammatical, but for most native speaker Anglophones it's seriously non-idiomatic.

Comment: The second "would" is used with dynamic modality, here involving propensity, but the first "would" expresses no such meaning. All that is required is the simple past tense "came" to convey the fact that she came to your house.

Comment: @Kate Bunting We don't normally say 'When I used to be a child I used to live in London/I lived in London. We usually say 'When I was a child I used to live in London.'  So 'every time she would...' is considered to be incorrect.

Comment: @BillJ I completely agree with you.

Comment: @MohammadFarukhAhmad - I know that - I am a well-read native speaker of English!!  I myself  would never use a sentence like the one the OP quoted, but I consider the examples found by LPH to be poorly written English rather than strictly incorrect.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I am happy to have a response from a well-read native speaker of English. Thank you for your swift response.

Comment: I'm a native English speaker from the UK. In my opinion your example is one of colloquial English. It's non-standard, but that doesn't make it wrong. However your observation is correct. In standard English it should be "Every time she came, she would ...".

Comment: We might say that the first "would" is redundant. It does not convey any kind of modality, and nor is it required to convey a past time meaning since this is done by "come" (i.e. "came").

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use 'Every time she **came** to our house, she **would** talk to Mom about that subject.'

We can also use 'Every time she **came** to our house, she **used to** talk to Mom about that subject.'

'Used to' comes first when we use them both together.

'Every time she **came** to our house, she **used to** talk to Mom about that subject. She **would** have lunch with her (Mom).